# Brackets and quotes being injected into returned results of SQL query

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to run an SQL query but the returned results keep coming back with brackets and quotes `''`.

The problem disappears if I query multiple columns, but the problem returns if I select one column only.

I've had a look around on google, not having any luck at this point in time.

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="xxxxxxxx",
  user="xxxxxxxx",
  passwd="xxxxxxxx",
  database="vmware"
)

query_string = "select UserID FROM VM WHERE CommissionStatus='commissioned';"

mycursor = mydb.cursor()

mycursor.execute(query_string)

ReturnedUser_id = []

for (User_id) in mycursor:
    ReturnedUser_id.append(User_id)
    print(User_id)
```

The problem seems to lie in the loop. In the case below, I'm selecting multiple columns, and there is no problem

```
for (User_id, VMName, VMTemplate) in mycursor:
    ReturnedUser_id.append(User_id)
    ReturnedVMName.append(VMName)
    ReturnedVMTemplate.append(VMTemplate)
    print(User_id)
```

OUTPUT:

```
32645845
32589456
32688145
```

And there's no annoying quotes or brackets or commas.

As soon as I query only one column, then this problem reappears again in the returned results.

```
for (User_id) in mycursor:
    ReturnedUser_id.append(User_id)
    print(User_id)
```

But only printing one column:

```
('32645845',)
('32589456',)
('32688145',)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax     `for (User_id) in mycursor:` is the   same as `for User_id in mycursor:`, here `mycursor` is a list of tuple. In order to use loop on a tuple of 1 element, you need to use `for (User_id,) in mycursor:`.

For example:

```
a = [(1,),(2,),(3,)]

for i in a:
    print(i)
#(1,)
#(2,)
#(3,)
for (i,) in a:
    print(i)
#1
#2
#3
```